# PhpStorm Warnings on JSON functions

Tags: php, json, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 7.1.3.

Whenever I use on of the PHP-built-in functions `json_encode` or `json_decode` PhpStorm says that this function is undefined.

[image: here's a screenshot]

I don't want to disable inspection for all undeclared functions. I also don't want to supress the inspection for every statement including json_*.

What's the easiest way to get rid of these warnings? Why do they even show up?

Comment: Screenshot of the error please. In any case: have you tried `File | Invalidate caches...` yet?

Comment: @LazyOne Wow, Invalidating and Restarting was the solution! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your indexes may have been corrupted somehow (for whatever reason, e.g. crash/improper shutdown) or are simply out of date (in case of upgrade from previous version).

Please use `File | Invalidate caches...` and restart IDE.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to check this box:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 5.5, some Linux distros switched to different JSON implementation (https://github.com/remicollet/pecl-json-c).

In case you're on Ubuntu (or some other Debian flavor), install the new JSON implementation using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

Comment: That's interesting to know but I'm using PhpStorm on Windows. The PHP-Interpreter on my computer already has JSON support so I don't know if installing it on Linux would make any difference here.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried with the above solutions:

- Running `File | Invalidate caches / Restart...`
- Checking the `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | PHP Runtime` and reassuring the missing checks were checked (in my case, it's synced with interpreter)

But none worked. So I decided to go a little bit forward and take a drastic solution. I removed the cache folder of the PHPStorm installation.

In Linux is under the `~/.cache/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.3` folder. Clearly, the path will depend on the PHPStorm version you use. I bet this could happen in other JetBrains IDEs, so it could be of use on Android Studio, or IntelliJ IDEA as well.